# Cocoa memory management rule

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-management

The Cocoa "Memory Management Programming Guide" document says:

> You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message. You are responsible for relinquishing ownership of objects you own using release or autorelease. Any other time you receive an object, you must not release it.

Does this also apply to the convenience methods like [NSNumber numberWithFloat:] or [CAAnimation animation]? Should I release these or not?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That statement is still true for convenience methods, in particular the last sentence

> Any other time you receive an object,
>   you must not release it.

This means that you must **not** release these objects unless you explicitly send them a retain message beforehand.

Comment: @Kay: Yes, they are autoreleased when they are returned from the convenience methods.

Comment: No, it means you don't have ownership of them and you should thus not release them. How their owners choose to manage their memory (retain+autorelease or not) is none of your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Those method names do not begin with `alloc` or `new`, nor contain `copy`, nor are they `retain`. So, no—you do not own the objects those methods return, so you should not release them.